# Partially fill a shape's border with colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-shapes

I am trying to create a progress effect whereby colour fills a DOM object's border (or possibly background). The image attached should give you a better idea of what I'm going for. I have achieved the current result by adding an object with a solid background colour over the grey lines and setting its height. This object has `mix-blend-mode: color-burn;` applied to it which is why it only colours the grey lines underneath it.

This works okay, but ruins the anti aliasing around the circle, and also the produced colour is unpredictable (changes depending on the colour of the lines).

I feel there must be a better way of achieving this, perhaps with the canvas element. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example]

Comment: What about creating two duplicate divs, set the top color'd version over hidden and adjust height accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you are saying. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Gradient? background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7db9e8 50%,#1e5799 50%);

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use a gradient as the circle is one object on top of the line which is another. Setting the background for the line would work but I'm not sure how I would set the background for the circle only when the colour reaches it. The text would be an issue for the same reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible to do with Canvas and may even be possible with CSS itself by playing with multiple elements etc but I would definitely recommend you to use SVG. SVG offers a lot of benefits in terms of how easy it is to code, maintain and also produce responsive outputs (unlike Canvas which tends to become pixelated when scaled).

The following are the components:

- A `rect` element which is the same size as the parent `svg` and has a `linear-gradient` fill. The gradient has two colors - one is the base (light gray) and the other is the progress (cyan-ish).
- A `mask` which is applied on the `rect` element. The mask has a `path` which is nothing but the line and the circle. When the `mask` is applied to the `rect`, only this `path` would show through the actual background (or fill) of the `rect`, the rest of the area would be masked out by the other `rect` which is added inside the `mask`.
- The `mask` also has a `text` element to show the progress value.
- The `linear-gradient` has the `stop offset` set in such a way that it is equal to the progress. By changing the `offset`, we can always make sure that the `path` shows the progress fill only for the required length and the base (light gray) for the rest.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var progress = document.querySelector('#progress'),
    base = document.querySelector('#base'),
    prgText = document.querySelector('#prg-text'),
    prgInput = document.querySelector('#prg-input');
  prgInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    prgText.textContent = this.value + '%';
    progress.setAttribute('offset', this.value + '%');
    base.setAttribute('offset', this.value + '%');
  });
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
path {
  stroke-width: 4;
}
#rect {
  fill: url(#grad);
  mask: url(#path);
}

/* just for demo */
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.controls * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 200 300' id='shape-container'>
  <linearGradient id='grad' gradientTransform='rotate(90 0 0)'>
    <stop offset='50%' stop-color='rgb(0,218,235)' id='progress' />
    <stop offset='50%' stop-color='rgb(238,238,238)' id='base' />
  </linearGradient>
  <mask id='path' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x='0' y='0' width='200' height='300'>
    <rect x='0' y='0' width='200' height='300' fill='black' />
    <path d='M100,0 100,100 A50,50 0 0,0 100,200 L100,300 M100,200 A50,50 0 1,0 100,100' stroke='white' />
    <text id='prg-text' x='100' y='155' font-size='20' text-anchor='middle' fill='white'>50%</text>
  </mask>
  <rect id='rect' x='0' y='0' width='200' height='300' />
</svg>

<!-- just for demo -->
<div class='controls'>
  <label>Set Progress:</label>
  <input type='range' id='prg-input' min='0' max='100' value='50' />
</div>
```

---

If you are new to SVG you can refer to the MDN Docs (links provided below) for more information about the elements, their attributes and values.

- [SVG Mask Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask)
- [SVG Tutorial on Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Comment: This sounds very promising! Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: You're welcome @BenGuest. Happy to help. I'm adding SVG tag also to the question. Hope you'd have no concerns on that :)

Comment: That's fine with me @Harry! Thanks again :)

Comment: *"unlike Canvas which **tends** to become pixelated when scaled"* -- more like _guaranteed_ to become pixelated, as it isn't vector based as SVG. :)

Comment: @JohnWhite: Oh yeah you are correct. There is a way to overcome it by repainting the entire stuff on window resize but that's too much work for what could be done easily with SVG.